# CSS Dynamic Grid

Tags: css

Excuse the title of the post - I am at a loss on how to describe the design problem I am attempting to implement... (which is likely stopping me from finding an appropriate solution).

I have a wireframe/comp that came from my designer:

[image]

Which, in terms of a grid, looks something like this:

[image]

Now... the obvious problem is how do I make certain content span two rows or columns of a grid or table ? B/C the way I read this, either the squarish logo on the left or the 'coming soon' text on the top needs to span across two fields...

Is this even possible ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's fairly easy. Did you try something that didn't work?

Comment: And what is so "asynchronous" in it ?

Comment: @c-smile *"Excuse the title of the post - I am at a loss on how to describe the design problem I am attempting to implement"* - OP

Comment: @Louy yes, of course I tried something... but nowherenear close enough to bother showing source code. I can see from your Edit that 'Dynamic' is what I should be looking at ?

Comment: Async means something that happens at different time. Dynamic means something that adapts. There's nothing "async" in css. Anyway you should look for something called "grids" and "grid systems".

Comment: Yeah I know... point taken.

Comment: I would highly recommend you understand the purpose of Tables to divisional elements.  Divs are for layout / content , Tables for tabular data.  Using Tables for layout is an outdated way of laying out any sort of website.

Comment: It's just one of the possible solutions that I explored, but thanks for the note.

Comment: Definitely, a great resource is "CSS tricks" allot of people explore and create new methods and styles there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to make each of the three sections a container using a div.

You can then position the elements as desired with adjustable margins and padding.

```css
.container{
  background: #333;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  height:auto;
  width:500px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.icon{
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">
    
  </div>
  <div class="coming-soon">
    COMING SOON TO MOBILE
  </div>
  <div class="downloads">
    <button>
     Apple
    </button>
    <button>
     Android
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If needed, you can target the coming-soon and downloads classes for more customization.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if I can help any further!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this. Here's one using `float:left` and nested `div`s.

```css
div {
  float: left;
}
#group {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
#three {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#four {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="group">
  <div id="two">
  </div>
  <div id="three">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="four">
</div>
```

Comment: That totally works. Wow, I've been leveraging Bootstrap so much, I need to review my vanilla CSS !

Comment: This will work, but its an over strain on the use of DIV's less is more, but again it does work no contesting that.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler layout would be to go.
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img style="float: left" src="your img" alt="whatevs"/>
<ul style="float:left">
<li><b>COMING SOON TO MOBILE</b></li>
<li><img src="1" alt="inline-block"/><img src="2" alt="inline-block"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Simple CSS

```
.wrapper ul li img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
}
```

The fact here is, the code is simplified, the layout is easy to read, its less divs, and far more less complicated. But, truth be, theres a 100 ways to do this so find the method that fits your size shoe best.